# inheritance and Overriding in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my JS code:

```
var Person=function(name,age)
{
   this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}

Person.prototype.calculateAge=function()
{
    console.log(2016-this.age);
}

var Teacher=function(salary)
{
    this.salary=salary;
}

Teacher.prototype.calculateAge=function() // Ovverriding the fucntion calculateAge
{
    console.log("welcome to my world");
}


var pp=new Person('john',31);  // creating object pp, pp.name // john

Teacher.prototype=pp;

var t= new Teacher(20);   // inherit name and age , t.name // john

// now here am confused 
  t.calculateAge() // 1990  but am ovverride it will print my console right 
  //
```

Can anyone please explain how can i override? Here when I am overriding calculate age function, by calling `t.calculateAge()` its printing inherited one

Comment: See this :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

Comment: i checked so many blogs and videos also, i confused, am overriding calculateAge funtion right, but whrn i calling t.calculateAge(), it will print latestone, but here printing parent , how we ovverride in this case, how its workes

Comment: Improved language and made formatting changes

Comment: okay @RahulGupta, You didn't understand my question ??  can i explain again

Answer (score 0):

This code work probably :

```
function  Person(name,age)
{
   this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
}

Person.prototype.calculateAge=function()
{
    console.log(2016-this.age);
}

function Teacher(salary)
{
    this.salary=salary;
}
Teacher.prototype = new Person();

Teacher.prototype.calculateAge=function() // Ovverriding the fucntion calculateAge
{
    console.log("welcome to my world");
}



var t= new Teacher(20);   // inherit name and age , t.name // john

// now here am confused 
  t.calculateAge() // 1990  but am ovverride it will print my console right 
  //
```

Comment: Yes, working but here i have small doubt, 
Teacher.prototype = new Person('john',20); 
var t=new teacher(20) //t.name=john, t.age=20 k fine,
But "I am overriding calculatingAge() fucntion in teacher Object, you are created object taking Teacher.prototype, i want person calculateAge() function, Then how we achieve ,

Thanks a lot for replying , I am confused a lot i have so many doubts #ZAhmed

Comment: here how to call  calculateAge()// Function for Person, t.calculateAge() it will print calculateAge()  for  Teacher object right

Comment: by this :   var l = new Person('ahmad',20);

       l.calculateAge();

Answer (score 0):

`Teacher.prototype.calculateAge = function() ...` should be after the line `Teacher.prototype = pp`.

Otherwise, `Teacher.prototype = pp` will reset `Teacher.prototype` to `pp`.

And, `t.calculateAge()` output `1985` for `2016 - 31 = 1985`.

Comment: Thanq @leaf but here i want to print override function() result, i.e console.log() o/p ,